# How to send parameters to queues?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1

Please consider the following job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ImportUsers extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number=$number;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        dd($this->number);
        return;
    }
}
```

Dispatching this job using a `sync` queue `$this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\ImportUsers(5));` throw this exception: `Undefined property: App\Jobs\ImportUsers::$number`. This really seems odd for me. Why the handle method can not access class properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Properly declare your property

```php
class ImportUsers extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $number; // <-- Here

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number=$number;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        dd($this->number);
        return;
    }
}
```

What happens is after the jobs is being deserialized from the queue you loose dynamically created property.

Try it:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Bus::dispatch(new App\Jobs\ImportUsers(7));
7
>>>
```