# Fail after adding parameters to job in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

A job I've written before without parameters now needs them. It's meant to send an email using the Mail class. I need to execute this job now with parameters but the queue is not seeing them.

I wonder if I'm initializing SendMailFinished in a wrong way but it should be ok.

I've read that there are issues with serialization but I added protected variables in SendMailFinished.

```
class ReporteBCH implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     * No hay que pasar ninguna variable.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Busca todos los equipos del inventario, luego revisa el SCCM con sus relaciones y el bginfo
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $msg = 'Proceso terminado. Ver ' . url('');
        $subj = 'Proceso BCH';
        $mailto = env('MAIL_TO');
        $send = new SendMailFinished($msg, $subj, $mailto);
        $send->dispatch();
    }


}
```

Now the thing is the process fails when I fire it from the console because it doesn't see parameters as if I didn't add them within the constructor.

SendMailFinished looks like this:

```
class SendMailFinished implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    protected $msg;

    protected $subj;

    protected $mailto;


    public function __construct($msg, $subj, $mailto)
    {
        //
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->subj = $subj;
        $this->mailto = $mailto;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Envia correo cuando termine cola.
        Mail::to($this->mailto)->queue(new TasksFinished($this->msg, $this->subj));
    }
}
```

The error is the following one:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\SendMailFinished::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\laragon\www\reportes\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable.php on line 26 and exactly 3 expected in C:\laragon\www\reportes\app\Jobs\SendMailFinished.php:31
```

I've read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#creating-jobs but there's not much to learn about it and also this one [How to send parameters to queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857298/how-to-send-parameters-to-queues)

Comment: How do you call it form console?

Comment: With a command class. which does just this \Log::info('Comienza creación reporte');
        $job = new ReporteBCH;
        
        $job->dispatch();

Comment: Sorry, I meant what do you type in console, when you try to call the command?

Comment: That's not relevant, the variables which I add are within the class, they don't need to be added before and I've used this job before with no issues before I added parameters to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer in the end is that arguments can't be passed as in a normal class and instead they have to be addded to the dispatch class all in one go.

This doesn't work:

```
$send = new SendMailFinished($msg, $subj, $mailto);
        $send->dispatch();
```

This works:

```
SendMailFinished::dispatch($msg, $subj, $mailto);
```

Found an [explanation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21339) within Laravel issues

Comment: this should also work: SendMailFinished::dispatch(new SendMailFinished($msg, $subj, $mailto));

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty relevant how you call your command. The problem is, when you define your variables in constructor, your command is expecting some data. If you call your command without that data, constructor won't get any data, and you will get an exception.

First of all, you need to change your command signature, to expect some parameters (if you didn't already) :

```
protected $signature = 'your:command {msg}{subject}{mailTo}'
```

Later, when you call your command, you need to pass all those arguments:

```
php artisan your:command parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
```

Read more at official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#defining-input-expectations).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question because the variables are inside the job. I just happen to execute that job from a command. It's the first piece of code I pasted above.

Comment: Did you try it? Your variables are defined in your job, but they are not getting any values, since you are not passing those values when calling the command.

Comment: The variables are inside the handle as pasted above.